# How to fix child element not getting height of its parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have a page like this:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pageWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: saddlebrown;
  height: 40px;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.innerWrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
    <div class="pageWrapper">
      <header class="header"></header>
      <main class="main">
        <div class="innerWrapper">
          <button>Button</button>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer class="footer"></footer>
    </div>
```

As I understand, `innerWrapper` is not getting 100% height of `main` because `main`'s height is not defined explicitly, it's `flex:1`. Is it correct? How do I make `innerWrapper` get the height of `main` in this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.main` is occupying its container's height/width. It is your `.innerWrapper` that is not occupying the height of its container.

The reason for this is that the height of `.main` is not explicit. According to [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height):

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly
> (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not
> absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'

You can change `.main` to be flex also and change `.innerWrapper` to have `flex: 1`:

```
.main {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange; // Added for visual only. Remove from your code.
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.innerWrapper {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[See it work here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ueaj7pb6/)

Comment: thanks. I know that main is occupying its height/width. Therefore, when I set innerWrapper to `height:100%` I was expecting it to get height from `main` and basically occupy all height as well

Comment: @Noob, I updated my answer to explain why the `height: 100%` does not work

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `flex` and the `heigh` properties from the children and add  `align-items: stretch;` and `display: flex;` to the parent.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pageWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: saddlebrown;
  height: 40px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.innerWrapper {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageWrapper">
      <header class="header"></header>
      <main class="main">
        <div class="innerWrapper">
          <button>Button</button>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer class="footer"></footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: add `display: inherit;` to `.innerWrapper`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the thing you are trying to achieve...

Check the code. I have added comments to identify the code which is added...

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pageWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: saddlebrown;
  height: 40px;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  background-color:blue;
}


.innerWrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*code added here*/
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  /* if you want to add button to center add this property here right:50%;*/
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageWrapper">
      <header class="header"></header>
      <main class="main">
        <div class="innerWrapper">
          <button>Button</button>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer class="footer"></footer>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the display value `block` instead of `flex` at the class `.innerWrapper`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pageWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: saddlebrown;
  height: 40px;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.innerWrapper {
  height:100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageWrapper">
  <header class="header"></header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <button>Button</button
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</div>
```